# Differentiable functions and existence of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

If a function is differentiable everywhere, does it imply that the limit at $\pm \infty$ is either finite or it diverges to $\pm \infty$?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto 0$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @copper.hat: The limits at $\pm\infty$ of $x\mapsto0$ (both exist and) are both finite; they are both $0.$

Comment: Yes, I do know what I was thinking.

Comment: Do not I mean...

Answer (score 4):

No, as the sine function shows. It has no limit at $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't. For example, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are infinitely differentiable functions, but they have no limit at $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Counter-examples: $f(x)=e^{-x^2},$ and $f(x)=x^2.$

Comment: But $e^{-x^2}$ *does* have a finite limit at $\pm\infty$ and $x^2$ diverges to $\infty$ at $\pm\infty$. Is this not what the OP was suggesting?

Comment: What I'm saying is that one of the functions is a counterexample to one side, and the other function is a counterexample to the other. $e^{-x^2}$ shows that a differentiable function need not have infinite limits at infinity. $x^2$ shows that a differential function need not have finite limits at infinity.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I was under the impression that the OP was separately considering each limit at $\pm\infty$, as opposed to considering them together. I think it's not entirely clear from their question.